# Adding two Numbers from ListNode and Returning a ListNode

Tags: python, list, loops

I am attempting a couple LeetCode exercises, and I managed to write 95% of a solution, but I could not figure the end out. I ended up looking at one of the solutions and saw it was similar to what I was doing. I was just wondering if someone could explain the end part of his solution for me:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        num1 = ''.join(joinList(l1)[::-1])
        num2 = ''.join(joinList(l2)[::-1])
        num3 = str(int(num1) + int(num2))[::-1]
        
        list = []
        
        for x in range(len(num3)):
            list.append(ListNode(int(num3[x])))

       ##################################
       #for x in range(len(list) - 1):  # <----------- Explain what this is doing, everything
       #    list[x].next = list[x + 1]  #              else I managed to write
       ##################################    
         
        return list[0]
        
def joinList(node):
    list = []
    x = node
    while x != None:
        list.append(str(x.val))
        x = x.next
    return list
```

The goal was to:

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

I am confused as to why list[0].next, list[1].next, would need to be set equal to list[x + 1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the `list` variable has `ListNode` entries in it. For example, if your sum turned out to be '1234', the `list` contains `[ListNode(1), ListNode(2), ListNode(3), ListNode(4)]`.

Notice however, that ListNode(1) doesn't have its `next` field set to anything, it is `None`. 
This is because when you wrote this piece of code: `list.append(ListNode(int(num3[x])))`, you're not really passing in any `next` value so it takes the default specified in the constructor which is `None`, you can see that here : `def __init__(self, val=0, next=None)`.

The same is true for ListNode(2), ListNode(3) and ListNode(4).

So now all that's left to be done is link ListNode(1) to ListNode(2) by changing ListNode(1)'s `next` variable to refer to `ListNode(2)`.
That's what the for loop in question is doing.